# POST 404 error when trying to test contact form in Next.js using localhost server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to test out a contact form in Next.js, it logs the data entered, but is not able to send the data to the API, keep getting an error

"POST http://localhost:3000/app/(pages)/api/contact/route.tsx 404 (Not Found)"

trying to find out what's wrong

[the directory setup] (image)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz5ch.png)

```
'use client'

import { useState, FormEvent } from "react"
import React from "react"

export const ContactForm = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    
    const onSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
    
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/app/(pages)/api/contact/route.tsx',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name, email, message
                }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            if (res.ok) {
                // Handle success
                console.log('Submission successful');
            } else {
                // Handle errors
                console.error('Submission failed');
            }
        } catch (err:any) {
            console.error('Err', err)
        }
    
    }
    
    
    return (
        <main>
            <form 
            className="contact-form"
            onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                    name="name"
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="NAME"
                    required/>
                <input
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    name="email"
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="EMAIL"
                    required/>
                <textarea
                    value={message}
                    onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                    name="message" 
                    id=""
                    placeholder="MESSAGE"
                />
                <button type="submit">SEND</button>
            </form>
        </main>
    )

}
```

The contact-form.tsx code

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){

    console.log('Data', req.body)
    
    res.status(200).json({name: "John Doe"})
}
```

the app/api/contact/route.tsx file code currently

attempted fixes

1. changed pages directory from "(pages)" to "pages"
2. copied path directly and copy-pasted it into fetch

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using NextJs 14. Convert the file name from app/api/contact/route.tsx into app/api/contact/route.ts

Replace the current code of route.ts with this

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json();

  return NextResponse.json({ body }, { status: 200 });
}
```

See the documentation for more https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response

Comment: Thank you for answer, It still gives 404 error after applying solution, I'll look at the docs and see what I can find

Comment: The directory should be like pages/api/contact/route.. According to the official site https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Comment: When a file is added to the pages directory, it's automatically available as a route.
then hit on  **http://localhost:3000/api/contact/route** and fetch data **/api/contact/route**

Comment: changed hose to this http://localhost:3000/app/(pages)/api/contact-form/route.ts, still doesn't appear to be working

Comment: The pages are in the app folder because the project is setup with the App Router in new version of Next, so they have to be nested under the app folder I believe

Comment: to update: I've managed to get it to find the route, I'm not getting a 405 error, looking through docks and google to try to resolve, here is the message "POST http://localhost:3000/api/contact 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the button and fetch the data never use an extension like 'route.tsx'

**On the client side**

```
 const res = await fetch('/pages/api/contact',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name, email, message
                }),
```

**On the Api Route Side**

When you make a directory like *'app/pages/api/contact/route.ts'*
it will detect file *'/pages/api/contact'*

```
 import {  NextResponse , NextRequest} from "next/server";
 
 export  async function POST(req:NextRequest)  {
 
 const { name,email,message } = await req.json()
 console.log(name,email,message);
 
   return NextResponse.json({mess:message})
 };
```

**The Folder Directory is here**

[image]

*I hope it will help you. good luck!*